# debug SQL command In C#

Tags: c#, sql, insert

//SQL command
                           string instStr = @" insert into dbo.cutComma
                                           ( big,
                                          small,
                                          allname,
                                          year,
                                          inv_typeid,
                                          cityid,
                                          districtid,
                                          villageid,
                                          name_01,
                                          id_01,
                                          sexid_01,
                                          birth_01,
                                          eduid_01,
                                          address_01,
                                          tel_01,
                                          name_02,
                                          id_02,
                                          birth_02,
                                          address_02,
                                          no_farm,
                                          name_farm,
                                          address_farm,
                                          tel_farm,
                                          animal_farm,
                                          amount_farm,
                                          animalid,
                                          subanimalid,
                                          raisecount,
                                          slaughter_inv,
                                          borncount,
                                          deadcount,
                                          byproductid,
                                          byproduct_inv,
                                          area,
                                          code,
                                          address_farm_01,
                                          sn,
                                          bigsmall_code,
                                          num_code
                                    )
                                          values(@big,
                                          @small,
                                          @allname,
                                          @year,
                                          @inv_typeid,
                                          @cityid,
                                          @districtid,
                                          @villageid,
                                          @name_01,
                                          @id_01,
                                          @sexid_01,
                                          @birth_01,
                                          @eduid_01,
                                          @address_01,
                                          @tel_01,
                                          @name_02,
                                          @id_02,
                                          @birth_02,
                                          @address_02,
                                          @no_farm,
                                          @name_farm,
                                          @address_farm,
                                          @tel_farm,
                                          @animal_farm,
                                          @amount_farm,
                                          @animalid,
                                          @subanimalid,
                                          @raisecount,
                                          @slaughter_inv,
                                          @borncount,
                                          @deadcount,
                                          @byproductid,
                                          @byproduct_inv,
                                          @area,
                                          @code,
                                          @address_farm_01,
                                          @sn,
                                          @bigsmall_code,
                                          @num_code                                 )";
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@big", LoadData[Loadi][0]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@small", LoadData[Loadi][1]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@allname", i);//拆逗號
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", LoadData[Loadi][8]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv_typeid", LoadData[Loadi][9]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityid", LoadData[Loadi][10]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@districtid", LoadData[Loadi][11]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@villageid", LoadData[Loadi][12]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_01", LoadData[Loadi][13]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_01", LoadData[Loadi][14]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexid_01", LoadData[Loadi][15]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth_01", LoadData[Loadi][16]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eduid_01", LoadData[Loadi][17]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_01", LoadData[Loadi][18]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel_01", LoadData[Loadi][19]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_02", LoadData[Loadi][20]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_02", LoadData[Loadi][21]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth_02", LoadData[Loadi][22]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_02", LoadData[Loadi][23]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no_farm", LoadData[Loadi][24]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_farm", LoadData[Loadi][25]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_farm", LoadData[Loadi][26]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel_farm", LoadData[Loadi][27]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@animal_farm", LoadData[Loadi][28]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount_farm", LoadData[Loadi][29]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@animalid", LoadData[Loadi][30]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subanimalid", LoadData[Loadi][31]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@raisecount", LoadData[Loadi][32]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slaughter_inv", LoadData[Loadi][33]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borncount", LoadData[Loadi][34]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deadcount", LoadData[Loadi][35]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@byproductid", LoadData[Loadi][36]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@byproduct_inv", LoadData[Loadi][37]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area", LoadData[Loadi][38]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", LoadData[Loadi][39]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address_farm_01", LoadData[Loadi][40]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", LoadData[Loadi][41]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bigsmall_code", LoadData[Loadi][42]);
                                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num_code", LoadData[Loadi][43]);

```
                                comm.CommandText = instStr;
                                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This is just a wall of code with no question, no description of a problem,  what you expect, or what it really does.

Answer (score -1):

after comm.CommandText = instStr;
      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

and then 
comm.parameter.clear()
in a loop